# make bootstrap tab refresh link when clicking on a tab

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `Bootstrap4.4.5` and trying to implement tabs as below:

```
<nav>
<div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
<a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="/home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="/profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="/contacts" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">...</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">... 
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">... 
</div>
</div>
```

Please notice that the `href` is pointing to a specified url in my project. Indeed, I am using `django` and capturing that url to call a handler and do some work. But it does not work. Bootstrap does not change my url

I tried to delete the attribute `data-toggle="tab"` but in that case, I see the url changing in the address field of my browser (for example becoming `www.mysite.com/profile` when I click the second tab), but the first tab stays active

Comment: how are you doing your routing -- we kind of need to see that code too

Comment: It is done automatically by django. When I put `href="/home"`, it will be routed to `www.mysite.com/home`

Answer (score 0):

The tab behaviour can be overriden by javascript like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item.nav-link").map((el) => el.addEventListener('click', (e) => { window.location.href( e.target.href ); }) )
```

(append it to your  tags)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me how to add it to the tags? (newbie here) Do you mean add an attribute `onclick`?